# failed to open stream: Invalid argument on Windows

Tags: php, windows

The following error occurs when saving a file.

*file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\EntisServer\data\documents\0762717314e01b7dc526ae5214b6a213dbbd1573.jpg
): failed to open stream: Invalid argument*

It seems I'm unable to find out what is meant by Invalid argument. One issue could have been that I was using a directory name using both unescaped backslashes. So, I added the escaped backslashes. Still, no luck. I think it is important to note that this code is operating on a Windows machine.

```
        $filename = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
        $this->path = $filename . '.' . $extension;

        $raw = base64_decode($base64);

                    if(file_put_contents('C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\EntisServer\\data\\documents\\'.$this->path, $raw)===false){
            throw new \Exception('Cannot write file: '.$this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->path);
        }
```

**Note 1:** may be important as well, the code is running from Netbeans using PHPUnit

**Note 2**: The code is part of a webservice when calling the webservice from an external source (not phpunit) the file gets saved. Any ideas?

Comment: @felipsmartins, yes, even changed the permissions to administrator rights on windows. Didn't help. What about try/catch? file_put_contents is not catchable

Comment: Maybe it can to help you: http://evertpot.com/filesystem-encoding-and-php/